# How can I change the Start Menu button in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I would like to change the icon used for Windows 7's start menu button.

Is it possible to replace the standard icon somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just download the Windows Orb Changer Utility and follow the automated wizard. 
You can find more information on it here [Orb Utility](http://www.techspot.com/guides/260-customize-windows-7-start-menu-button/)